# Remove dependency to non-existing database table (sql server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server-2008, dependencies

I want to update a table in sql server 2008 R2. It fails because the table has a dependency to a table which does not exist any more ("unresolved entity"). I would like to remove the dependency. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency is created by some sort of table key, trigger etc. 
All of these have to be checked and if necessary, removed.